# heroku newbie: "web dyno + work dyno" mode v.s. 'classical' mode

Tags: django, heroku

[ -- SKIP THIS INTRODUCTORY PART -- ]

I'm introducing myself to heroku platform (with django). I'm following the [Heroku Django tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using_a_different_wsgi_server). In tutorial 'step' *Now we’re ready to scale up a worker:* I execute command and this message appears:

```
(venv)dani@heroku-test:~/hellodjango$ heroku ps:scale celeryd=1
Scaling celeryd processes...  
 !    Please verify your account in order to change resources
 !    For more information, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing
 !    Verify now at http://heroku.com/verify
```

After digging heroku web, I see that the issue is that I should inform about my credit car because *running more than one dyno (1 web dyno + 1 work dyno) for an extended period may incur charges*

Also, reading tutorial, heroku says that: *for production apps, you should use a production-ready embedded webserver Gunicorn and gevent.* I appreciate a lot the possibility to scale my application.

Which brings us to ...

[ -- START READING HERE -- ]

... my question(s):

- Can I starting running an application in heroku without "web dyno + work dyno" mode? Someone has experience running without celerity?
- For a limited corporate 'intranet' application, (a platform like) heroku worth?

Any comment will be wellcome. Thanks for share your expertise. Sorry about this newbie question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heroku's support answer:

chris, May 21 12:38 (PDT):
Hi,

- Can I starting running an application in heroku without "web dyno + work dyno" mode without problems? (just like first part of django quick start or you recommend to upgrade to 15G + 2 dynos = 50€ moth)

> You should be able to run your app with a single web dyno for free.
>   You'll need to scale up to take on additional traffic though. In order
>   to scale up you will have to verify your account w/ a credit card.

- For a limited corporate 'intranet' application, is heroku a good solution (in money terms)?

> Yes. Of course this all comes down to what you think is a reasonable
>   amount to spend to run your corporate application.

Cheers,
-Chris